# ln: failed to create symbolic link "Function not implemented

Tags: filesystem, external-hdd, symbolic-link

Hello I have searched mutliple threads on "Function not implemented" for symbolic link but none of the threads I've found have helped.

I'm trying to create a symbolic link on my external drive.

```
sudo ln -s /media/user/externaldrivename/test.wav /media/user/externaldrivename/test2.wav
```

but i get the error

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/user/externaldrivename/test2.wav': Function not implemented
```

this is what i get when I run `mount`

> /dev/sda1 on /media/kankawabata/kanswork_hd type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)

I am not that experienced with this issue. I have used the instruction found here to mount exFat drives before and was wondering maybe this is the cause of the issue.

https://www.howtogeek.com/235655/how-to-mount-and-use-an-exfat-drive-on-linux/

Comment: I think that's likely a limitation of the exfat filesystem - see for example [Linux links (shortcuts) in exfat filesystem](https://superuser.com/questions/1256530/linux-links-shortcuts-in-exfat-filesystem/1256536)

Answer (score 2):

If you connected to an SMB/FTP/.. (etc) file systems remotely, you can't create a hard link (security policy). You should create a soft link.

So you can use the `ln` command like that:

```
ln -s file1.txt new-soft-link.txt
```

It's hardlink-like, but not written physically to the Inodes partition section.